# Building one project for automated multiple environment deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, automation, build-process, ear

The project I'm working on needs to be deployed to multiple environments. It's a Websphere 8.5 J2EE application. The 6 environments that we deploy to and their following server types are:

- LOCAL (Websphere Liberty 8.5 for Developers)
- DEV (WAS v8.5)
- TEST (WAS v8.5)
- UAT (WAS v8.5)
- STAGING (WAS v8.5)
- PRODUCTION (WAS v8.5)

Each environment (server) needs to have its files tweaked slightly (ex: TEST has a different database name than UAT, LOCAL needs certain files to skip the login process than the other servers, etc).

Currently, we manually modify every file necessary depending on the environment we need to deploy to - which is repetitive and takes time. Is there some type of system we can use to automate this? Ideally, I'd like to just have to click one button for deployment to begin, depending on where I want to deploy to.

Thanks!

EDIT: I have no experience in automated deployment, so any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT2: We are deploying .EAR files

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I understand your question... you have a ear that needs to be deployed to multiple environments. Each time you need to modify something in the ear and rebuild it and deploy.

I think you are not using JNDI efficiently in your application. An application should get the database related settings and other parameters by using simple lookup to the JNDI. This would ensure that when you deploy in different environments you get different values for the database connection and other params.

Comment: It's a project I'm maintaining, so there's a lot of bad code that I can't fix. I now have it set up so there see a few java property files that need to have their values changed depending on the environment that's being deployed to. I started using Gradle to automate the modifications to the .properties files. Are you familiar with Gradle at all?